# Do I need a multiple entry visa for a trip UK -> Sweden -> UK?

Tags: visas, uk

My wife and I are travelling to the UK. We are visiting a friend staying over for three nights. We then leave for Sweden for twelve days coming back to the UK via Scotland for 2nights. Do we need a multiple entry visa or do we just fill out the standard visa application?

Comment: When are you travelling? I'm not really familiar with how visas issued for one of the Schengen country works for others but to my understanding you need one issued by any of the countries. Unfortunately it will remain true only until Brexit is going to happen. Afterwards you'll most probably need separate visas for UK and Sweden.

Comment: @Ister I am afraid your comment is based on false premise - UK is not (and for a long time not been, if not never) in the Schengen zone due to the opt-out negotiated.

Comment: @B.Liu: It's "never".

Comment: Someone who may have been you asked "Should we then only add our arrival date and date of first departure in the online application?"  I would mention the entire itinerary at the first possible moment in the application, so as to reduce the possibility of being given a single-entry visa.  But do note that depending on your nationality you might not need a visa at all, and that also depending on your nationality, you might need a visa for Sweden.  If you do need a visa for Sweden, you will have to apply for that separately.

Comment: On all questions of this nature, _it is imperative to know your nationality_.

Comment: @B.Liu hmm, I must say I didn't check details. When I travelled to UK all I needed was my national Id (I'm a EU citizen) and I thought it's because of Schengen.

Comment: @Ister No, it was because at that point the UK was still a member of the EU. ID cards are no longer accepted unless the traveller meets certain criteria https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk

Comment: Yep, I'm aware they no longer accept EU national ID. Last year I've been to London (flying from Zurich to complicate things even further) and had to bring my passport with me.

Answer (score 15):

The UK Standard Visitor visa is always issued as a multiple entry visa valid for 6 months, unless UKVI see a compelling reason to curtail the number of entries or validity period. Just provide the dates you plan to be in the UK in the application.

Edit: When completing the application I would provide the initial date of arrival and the final exit date in the ’Travel information’ section of the application. In the ‘Accommodation details’ section you can then enter your specific UK travel plan dates, and the address(es) where you’ll be staying if known. You can also use the ‘Extra information’ section at the end of the application to explain your plan to visit Sweden from the UK.

Answer (score 8):

I'm guessing that you do not have a European passport and that you do not have visa exemption from either of these countries. In that case you will need a visa for the UK and another (Schengen) visa for Sweden. You're flying direct between the UK and Sweden I assume?

The UK has never been a part of the Schengen scheme.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that there could be *two* visas required for this trip (and, by implication of the stated assumption, that there might be *no* visas required for it, if the traveler's nationality exempts him from the visa requirement in both countries).  Welcome to the site.